# Sort a list numerically in Python

Tags: python, list, numbers, numeric, sorting

So I have this list, we'll call it listA. I'm trying to get the [3] item in each list e.g. `['5.01','5.88','2.10','9.45','17.58','2.76']` in sorted order. So the end result would start the entire list over again with Santa at the top. Does that make any sense?

`[['John Doe', u'25.78', u'20.77', '5.01'], ['Jane Doe', u'21.08', u'15.20', '5.88'], ['James Bond', u'20.57', u'18.47', '2.10'], ['Michael Jordan', u'28.50', u'19.05', '9.45'], ['Santa', u'31.13', u'13.55', '17.58'], ['Easter Bunny', u'17.20', u'14.44', '2.76']]`

Comment: Use itemgetter() from the operator module. It is not well know, but is designed to do exactly what you want. It is easier to read than lambdas and very simple to implement.

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson, unfortunately itemgetter won't help with sorting the strings numerically.

Comment: True. But it is still good to be aware of itemgetter  for everyone that comes to this page from google looking for a similar solution where the values are already float/int

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return the complete list in sorted order, this may work. This takes your input list and runs `sorted` on top of it. The `reverse` argument set to `True` sorts the list in reverse (descending) order, and the `key` argument specifies the method by which to sort, which in this case is the `float` of the third argument of each list:

```
In [5]: l = [['John Doe', u'25.78', u'20.77', '5.01'] # continues...    
In [6]: sorted(l, reverse=True, key=lambda x: float(x[3]))
Out[6]:
[['Santa', u'31.13', u'13.55', '17.58'],
 ['Michael Jordan', u'28.50', u'19.05', '9.45'],
 ['Jane Doe', u'21.08', u'15.20', '5.88'],
 ['John Doe', u'25.78', u'20.77', '5.01'],
 ['Easter Bunny', u'17.20', u'14.44', '2.76'],
 ['James Bond', u'20.57', u'18.47', '2.10']]
```

If you only need the values in sorted order, the other answers provide viable ways of doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
>>> listA=[['John Doe', u'25.78', u'20.77', '5.01'], ['Jane Doe', u'21.08', u'15.20', '5.88'], ['James Bond', u'20.57', u'18.47', '2.10'], ['Michael Jordan', u'28.50', u'19.05', '9.45'], ['Santa', u'31.13', u'13.55', '17.58'], ['Easter Bunny', u'17.20', u'14.44', '2.76']]

>>> [x[3] for x in sorted(listA, reverse = True, key = lambda i : float(i[3]))]
['17.58', '9.45', '5.88', '5.01', '2.76', '2.10']
```

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous `lambda` function is not necessary for this task. You can use `operator.itemgetter`, which may be more intuitive:

```
from operator import itemgetter

res1 = sorted(map(itemgetter(3), listA), reverse=True, key=float)

['17.58', '9.45', '5.88', '5.01', '2.76', '2.10']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
lstA.sort(reverse = True, key = itemgetter(3))
```

And you are good to go. Using itemgetter() within a sort is extremely helpful when you have multiple indexs to sort on. Lets say you wanted to sort alphabetically on the first value in case of a tie you could do the following

```
from operator import itemgetter
lstA.sort(key = itemgetter(0))
lstA.sort(reverse = True, key = itemgetter(3))
```

And Voilà!